# Plotting fibre direction at each node

Tags: finite-element-method, modeling, acegen

I was wondering if there was a way to plot the direction vector of a fibre family at each node in AceGen/AceFem? Below is an example of exactly what I want to do but I do not know how to recreate it.[image]
The direction vector is (Cos[41], Sin[41], 0]^T. Thanks.

Comment: It's always good to add the code you already have, otherwise I have to come up with something.

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this:

```
r = RegionDifference[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 9/10]];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[r];
rmf = RegionMember[r];
coords = Take[mesh["Coordinates"], {1, -1, 25}];
Show[
 VectorPlot3D[{Cos[41], Sin[41], 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> None, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    With[{rmf = rmf}, Function[{x, y, z}, rmf[{x, y, z}]]], 
   VectorPoints -> coords, VectorStyle -> Black, 
   VectorScale -> Small] /. 
  Arrow[x_] :> Arrow[{Mean[x], Mean[x] + Last[x] - First[x]}]
 ,
 mesh["Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[LightGray]}]]]
 ]
```

[image]

I have used some of the mesh points, but you could use anything; like a more regular base for the starting points of the vectors.